# Subscription a topic from another package

Tags: ros, subscribe, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Below is my code that publishes laser scanner messages and one line that is supposed to subscribe a topic of "pose2D" from another package called [laser_scanner_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher) package. I've also referred to the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) and am interested to follow what is described in section 2.3.2 using Class Methods, but, it still does not work. Perhaps, one can go to what I've commented out "This subscription does not work" that is needed to be corrected.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include <vector>
#include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h"
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include "tf/tf.h"
#include "tf/transform_datatypes.h"
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include "pcl/common/angles.h"


using namespace std;


const int num_row = 264;
const int num_column  = 1089;

class PointCloud
{
private:
    ros::NodeHandle n;
//  ros::Publisher chatter_pub;
    ros::Publisher scan_pub;
    ros::Publisher pose_pub;

    int count;
    vector<vector<double> > data_set;


public:
    PointCloud();
    ~PointCloud();

    /**
     * Opens and reads file
     */
    bool operateFile();
    void publishLaser();
//  void display(); //translate and publish

};

    PointCloud::PointCloud()
    {
        scan_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/scan", 50);
//      This subscription does not work
        sub = n.subscribe("/pose2D", 1, this);
        count = 0;

    }



    PointCloud::~PointCloud()
    {
        ROS_INFO("Shutting down publisher_node node.");
    }


    /**
     *  @brief Opens and reads file for further processing
     *
     *  @param
     *
     *  @return True if the file is successfully manipulated
     */
    bool PointCloud::operateFile()
    {

        ifstream inFile;  // object for reading from a file
        ofstream outFile; // object for writing to a file
        char inputFilename[] = "/home/alfa/ros_workspace/dataset1.txt";
        inFile.open(inputFilename, ios::in);

        if (!inFile) {
          cerr << "Can't open input file " << inputFilename << endl;
          exit(1);
        }
        else
            cout << "The file is successfully opened :-)" << endl;

        // Set up sizes. (num_row x num_column)
        data_set.resize(num_row);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_row; ++i)
            data_set[i].resize(num_column);

        // Store in a buffer/vector what have been read.
        for (int j = 0; j < num_row; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < num_column; k++)
            {
                inFile >> data_set[j][k];
            }


        return (true);
    }


    void PointCloud::publishLaser()
    {
        int num_laser_readings;
        double laser_frequency;

        num_laser_readings = 1080;

        laser_frequency = 40; //20 could be


        ros::Rate r(1.0);


        int t = 0;


        while (n.ok() && (t < num_row))
        {
            sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan;


            ros::Time scan_time( double(data_set[t][1]/1000));



            for (int i = 0; i < num_row; i++)
            {
                scan.header.stamp =  scan_time;
            }

            scan.header.frame_id = "laser_frame";
            scan.angle_min = - 270 / 2 * M_PI / 180; // -xx degree
            scan.angle_max = 270 / 2 * M_PI / 180;   // xx degree

            scan.angle_increment = (scan.angle_max-scan.angle_min)/num_laser_readings;

            scan.time_increment = (1 / laser_frequency) / (num_laser_readings);
            scan.range_min = 0.0;
            scan.range_max = 100.0;

            scan.set_ranges_size(num_laser_readings);

            for(int i = 0; i < num_laser_readings; ++i)
            {
//              Laser scanner data reside in column 10th to 1080th
                scan.ranges[i] = data_set[t][i+9] / 1000.0;
            }


            scan_pub.publish(scan);
            ++count;
            ++t;

            r.sleep();
        }
    }



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "publisher_node");
    PointCloud pointCloud;
    ROS_INFO("Node started");
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    pointCloud.operateFile();
    pointCloud.publishLaser();

    ROS_INFO("Node finished");

    return 0;

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12238/subscription-a-topic-from-another-package/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you need to create a class method that will be called each time a new message is received from /pose2D topic (I will assume that it publishes geometry_msgs/Pose2D messages):

```
void PointCloud::pose_callback(const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr& message)
{
    // process the message here
}
```

Then to create a subscriber to /pose2D topic you would do:

```
pose_sub = n.subscribe("/pose2D", 1, &PointCloud::pose_callback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-19**:
dornhege: Thanks for the answer.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-19**:
you don't. ros::spin() does.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-18**:
@arebgun and @dornhege: How do I invoke the callback function from main function? I am confused because it requires input parameters to be passed there.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-07**:
@dornhege: Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-07**:
The datatype always has the same name as the message. I.e. a geometry_msgs/Pose2D will be available as geometry_msgs::Pose2D in c++.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
@arebgun: I'm just curious how did you know/decide that the type of "Pose2DConstPtr" will suit this? Any hint for that..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
By the way, why do we actually need the callback function, if any can clarify..after reading the tutorial, I just got it on the surface, but I believe if somebody can explain this, it would be great to see the thing in this regard.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
It's solved already, my bad, I've changed this "geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr" to something else..Thanks a lot @arebgun and @dornhege.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
The above error message was obtained in a terminal upon running the nodes.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
How to correct if I got this message format error: "[ERROR] [1323243574.662154822]: Client [/publisher_node] wants topic /pose2D to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/Pose/e45d45a5a1ce597b249e23fb30fc871f], but our version has [geometry_msgs/Pose2D/938fa65709584ad8e77d238529be13b8]. Dropping conne"

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
@dornhege: Thanks a lot..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-06**:
You can use rostopic echo to see if messages are published on a topic.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
@arebgun:How do I check whether it is publishing fine or not in my code? I've tried using "cout" but it doesn't work..Thanks anyway..

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-12-06**:
Right, that's a typo, it is fixed now. Thanks!

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-06**:
@arebgun: Thanks a lot for the guide..I think there's a typo perhaps of in the second block of code which is &this, with this, it gives an error "lvalue required as unary "&" operand"..Once, I changed this variable without "&", it returns no error..it is a typo right?